# Can we retrieve a particular method from json file and display it on UI ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json

Hi everyone, I am new to iphone development..I am doing some application where I am stuck...I am having a textfield, button and a webview..

I am having a parsed json file..

I want to enter a string  or method in the textfield, which is present in the JSON file..It should match with the method in json file and should display the contents of a method on webview..

I have done with button and a webview... I want to extend further with textfield and webview..

How can we do it? Please suggest me with example code...

//code

```
 - (void)loadData
    {
        dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"]]retain];  

          [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }


    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        [connection release];    
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        self.dataWebService = nil;

        NSArray* latestLoans = [(NSDictionary*) [responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"loans"]; 

        [responseString release];    

        NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];

        //fetch the data
        NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];

        NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];

        float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

        NSString* name = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];

        NSString* country = [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"];

        //set the text to the label
        label.numberOfLines = 0;

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ \n \n country:  %@ \n \n amount: $%.2f", name,country,outstandingAmount];
 }
```

Comment: If an answer starts with "I think you are asking...", then we've got a bit of a problem.

Comment: I tried to edit the question so it would be more clear what the user is asking, (after he commented my answer) but my edit got rejected. Maybe I missed a rule somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking this: "How can I enter part of the URL in a textfield, and have it appended to a base URL and loaded into the webview?"

If so, you can do it quite easily. If your textfield is called "textfield" and webview called "webview" then do this:

```
NSString *baseUrl = @"http://whatever.com";
NSString *fullUrl = [baseUrl stringByAppendingString:textfield.text];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl]]];
```

Trigger it either with a button press or with UITextFieldDelegate's `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`

**Edit**:

You want to retrieve a value from the NSDictionary that the JSON generated based on a key you specify in the textfield. First, do

```
NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:textfield.text];
```

to get the value (assuming it is a string here). Then you want to display the value in a webview. You can either do it with `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` or with javascript via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` (both methods of UIWebView). If you want to use loadHTMLString for example you can put in

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</body></html>", value];
[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for ur response...no what i mean is i am already calling a method using a label in the above code....so what i need is for example...if i enter a method like funded_amount or country in a TextField it shd collect the value of tat from json file and display it on webview..i think u got my point?is tat possible to do?